# Как переопределить сигнал в qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня вопрос как переопределить сигнал в Qt?

Я переопределил `QCheckBox()`  и изменил сигнал `stateChanged`.

Проект собирается и работает. При этом не выводит в "выводе приложения" ошибок  либо сообщений типа "сигнал с слотом не связался"

НО не связывает с слотом. Не могу понять что не так.

---

Вот так работает :

```
 connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW()));// от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"
```

Хочу доработать, чтобы еще строку, сигнал оправлял :

```
connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int, QString)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString))); // от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"
```

---

переопределение QCheckBox-а

.h

```
#ifndef MYDIMASCHECKBOX_H
#define MYDIMASCHECKBOX_H

#include <QCheckBox>

class MyDimasCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDimasCheckBox(QWidget *parent =0);
    ~MyDimasCheckBox();

    QString stroka;
signals:
    void stateChanged(int, QString);
};

#endif // MYDIMASCHECKBOX_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "mydimascheckbox.h"

MyDimasCheckBox::MyDimasCheckBox(QWidget *parent)
{
    stroka = "dimasik :3";
    emit stateChanged(int(), stroka);
}
MyDimasCheckBox::~MyDimasCheckBox()
{

}
```

А вот где вызываю

.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QThread>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "mydimascheckbox.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    int glob_i ;
    int glob_flow;
    int vector_schet; // датчик счёта

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void start_sending(bool); // принажатии на чекбокс то выполниться этот слот (отправка сообщений)

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    QVector<QThread*> vector_thread;

    QList<MyDimasCheckBox*> test_checkbox;  // 16/08
    MyDimasCheckBox *checkBox = new MyDimasCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс через новый класс

    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
    // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget);
};

class NewsThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void run_NEW(); // код выполняемый в потоке
    void run_NEW(int, QString); // код выполняемый в потоке

signals:
    void otprawka (int);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    glob_i=0;
    glob_flow =0;
    vector_schet =0;


    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    test_checkbox.clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    glob_i++;

    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new MyDimasCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    test_checkbox.append(checkBox);

    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending

    checkBox->setText(QString::number(glob_i));

    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой

    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)

    qDebug() << "glob_i: " << glob_i;
}

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
    qDebug() << "start_sending  "  ;
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        NewsThread *two_cl = new NewsThread(); // инициализируем второй класс

        qDebug() << "chekbocks: "<< " TRUE" ;
        for (int i =0;i < test_checkbox.length();i++ )
        {
            if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() ==Value)
            {
                glob_flow++;

//                connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW()));// от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"
                connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int, QString)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString))); // от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"


                thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока из за того что
                vector_thread.append(thread);

                vector_schet++;
                qDebug() << "vector_schet : " << vector_schet ;
                two_cl->moveToThread(vector_thread[vector_schet-1]); // отправляем в поток
                vector_thread[vector_schet-1]->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке (второй поток)

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
        glob_flow--;
        qDebug() << "vector_schet : " << vector_schet ;
        vector_thread[vector_schet-1]->exit();
    }
}

void NewsThread::run_NEW()
{
    qDebug() << "run_NEW()";
    for(;;){ // вечный цикл
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
            qDebug()<< "Число :" << i <<"номер \"потока\" :"  ;
            usleep(100000);
        }
    }
}

void NewsThread::run_NEW(int i, QString str){
    qDebug() << "run_NEW(int i, QString str) ";
    for(;;){ // вечный цикл
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
            qDebug() << " i : " << i;
            qDebug() << " str : " << str;
            qDebug()<< "Число :" << i <<"номер \"потока\" :"  ;
            usleep(100000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? И что вы подразумеваете под переопределением сигнала?

Comment: @gil9red Вот, дополнил

Comment: У вас ваш сигнал вызывается только в конструкторе `emit stateChanged(int(), stroka);`, поэтому он никогда не будет вызван, т.к. соединение сигнала с слотом будет после вызова конструктора. Создайте в вашем классе метод, который вызовет сигнал и при нужных событиях вызывайте метод, либо вне класса вызывайте сигнал, что-то такое: `emit test_checkbox[i].stateChanged(0, "123");`

Comment: @gil9red      `connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(READ()), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString)));  вывел мне  :QObject::connect: No such signal MyDimasCheckBox::READ()`   Не вышло, так не работает

Comment: откуда вы взяли сигна `READ` если у вас он `stateChanged`?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver  я послушал совет gil9red-а и создал метод в который положил emit сигнала  stateChanged после чего положил в connect в позицию слота этот метод (да я знаю, это не правильно но я просто не понял как по другому делать )

Comment: Из вашей же строчки `SIGNAL(READ())` даже без чтения документации следует, что в этом месте функция `connect` хочет непосредственно сигнал, который должен быть присоединен к слоту, а не непонятный метод. Вам же в сообщении об ошибке английским по белому написано - "нет такого сигнала READ"

Comment: @BeardedBeaver да я знаю, НО как решить ???? я попробовал совет подумал а вдруг (либо просто не понял смысла совета ибо я не очень хорош  в этом деле)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver почему был удалён тэг "многопоточность" ведь  создаю отдельный поток.

Comment: потому что ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к многопоточности, это базовый вопрос по использованию механизма сигналов и слотов

Answer (score 1):

Ответ находиться [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040664/how-to-override-a-signal-in-qt/51040903#51040903)

Но так как я приверженец своей культуры я его выложу здесь переведенный ответ.*(еще там мои поправки удалили и теперь он более тяжёл для понимания)*

Перегрузить сигнал не получиться но можно направить сигнал на слот в котором будет лежать иной сигнал от другого коннекта к другому слоту. Для этого потребуется добавить в код один коннект.

В классе переопределения QCheckBox-а
.h

```
class MyDimasCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDimasCheckBox(QWidget *parent =0);
    ~MyDimasCheckBox();

    QString stroka;
private slots:
    // Создаём новый сигнал
    void doEmitStateChanged(int i);

signals:
    void stateChanged(int, QString);
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "mydimascheckbox.h"

MyDimasCheckBox::MyDimasCheckBox(QWidget *parent) : QCheckBox(parent) {

    // Connect original signal to slot
       connect(this, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(doEmitStateChanged(int)));
}
MyDimasCheckBox::~MyDimasCheckBox()
{

}

void MyDimasCheckBox::doEmitStateChanged(int i) {
    stroka = "dimasik :3";
    emit stateChanged(i, stroka);
}
```

---

А там где вызываю, заменяю код  с:

```
  //             connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW()));// от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"
  connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int, QString)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString))); // от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"
```

на:

```
 connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int, QString)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW(int, QString)));
```

Comment: У вас опять код неправильный в ответе. Первый connect не нужен в разделе `на`, он вызывается в конструкторе вашего чекбокса

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Ого он работает, спасибо . Ну у меня он работал и ошибок не выдавал.

Comment: Потому что вы просто присоединили один сигнал к слоту дважды, в этом случае при одном испускании сигнала слот будет вызван дважды. Фактической ошибки в этом, возможно, нет, но это не вполне корректное поведение.